# Error while trying to publish to MavenLocal - Fixed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, maven

I'm developing a library and I want to publish it to Maven Local for testing purposes...

While running the command in the terminal:

```
./gradlew publishToMavenLocal
```

I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'wfe'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.1.2
         project : > com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:8.1.2
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally
, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

When trying to publish using tasks, it builds but only generates the .pom

```
Gradle > wfe > Tasks > publishing > publishToMavenLocal
```

I've searched and trying to set the JDK to 17 and 11 but didnt work... I'm pretty newbie in this field of publishing to maven, so no idea what is happening...

Anyway, thanks!

**UPDATE - FIXED**

After some extra research I found out that I needed to add the following code to my build.gradle inside android tag:

```
publishing {
    singleVariant("release") {
        withSourcesJar()
        withJavadocJar()
    }
}
```

Comment: How have you configured the Java version to be used?

Comment: File > Settings > Build ... > Build tools > gradle > gradle jdk
Is that what you mean?

Comment: And in which terminal do you execute the Gradle command? The one inside Android Studio or a common terminal of your OS? Because the settings you make in Android Studio can only affect builds triggered by Android Studio.

Comment: android studio teminal

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I would assume the JDK setting for Gradle should be effective for the terminal inside AS. Because the error should disappear when you use JDK 17. But you can make sure the configured JDK is used by executing the Gradle command by Ctrl+Return instead of just Return key. Then AS will execute it as run config and not the terminal.

Comment: Crtl + return generates only the .pom

Comment: Please do not include the answer into your question. If you found the solution you can answer your own question, but please create a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**

After some extra research I found out that I needed to add the following code to my build.gradle inside android tag:

```
publishing {
    singleVariant("release") {
        withSourcesJar()
        withJavadocJar()
    }
}
```